# Find the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in $(1+x^{1} + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + x^{6})^6$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in  $(1+x^{1} + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5} + x^{6})^6$

Any direction or hint would be appreciated

Comment: It will always be new to you if you're just asking for a detailed solution to turn in as your own.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @openyourmouth has stated the solution, but I am wondering if this problem can be done in another way. If we think of $1$ as $x^0$, then by looking for the coefficient of $x^{21}$, we are simply looking for the number of ways to add $6$ (not necessarily distinct) elements of the set $S=\lbrace 0,1,2,3,...,6\rbrace$ to get $21$. Not sure how complex this problem becomes if we view it this way, just thought it might be interesting to consider.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear. I suggest you argue as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191469/find-the-coefficient-of-x20-in-x2⋯x6-5?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Notice that it is
$$\left(\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}\right)^6$$
Now, using binomial theorem:
$$(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$$
you get two polynomials, divide them until you reach $x^{21}$, you'll find that the solution is $7872$.

Comment: Can you explain how can I divide numerator and denominator?

Comment: @GADI. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division